# Need assistance on final bit of script if possible

Tags: python

Here are the prequisites for my script

```
"Generate a string with N opening brackets ("[") and N closing brackets     ("]"), in some
arbitrary order. You will need to use random numbers.
Determine whether the generated string is balanced; that is, whether it     consists entirely of
pairs of opening/closing brackets (in that order), none of which mis-nest.
Examples:
 [] OK ][ NOT OK
[][] OK ][][ NOT OK
[[][]] OK []][[] NOT OK
```

"

I have come up with this and thought i was done, however i just reliased that it doesnt quite get over the line because i get a positive result with "[]]["

can someone help me with achieving this part "pairs of opening/closing brackets (in that order),"

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import string
import random


def brackets():
count = 0


sample = [random.choice(['[', ']', '[]']) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))] 
sample2 =''.join([random.choice(['[', ']', '[]']) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))])


count1 = sample2.count('[')
count2 = sample2.count(']')


for x in sample2: 
    if x == "[":
        count +=1 
    if x == "]":
        count -=1

if count != 0 or count < 0 :
    print "The generated sample is %s " % (sample2,)
    print "There are %d [ in the generated string" % (count1,)
    print "There are %d ] in the generated string" % (count2,)
    print "This string is Not ok"


if count == 0 :
    print "The generated sample is %s " % (sample2,)
    print "There are %d [ in the generated string" % (count1,)
    print "There are %d ] in the generated string" % (count2,)
    print "This string is ok"



print brackets()
```

Comment: Some specific question?

Comment: can someone help me with achieving this part "pairs of opening/closing brackets (in that order),"

Answer (score 2):

Here's a funny little idea I had. It basically works by seeing whether or not all the bracket pairs can be turned into individual lists:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def valid(s):
    if any(c not in '[]' for c in s): return False
    try:
        literal_eval(s.replace('[]', '[],'))
        return True
    except SyntaxError:
        return False
```

This (I believe) should work every time, including with the examples you gave:

```
>>> valid('[]')
True
>>> valid('][')
False
>>> valid('[][]')
True
>>> valid('][][')
False
>>> valid('[[][]]')
True
>>> valid('[]][[]')
False
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use Staks. Code below will give you the answer:

```
from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack

def parChecker(symbolString):
    s = Stack()
    balanced = True
    index = 0
    while index < len(symbolString) and balanced:
        symbol = symbolString[index]
        if symbol in "([{":
            s.push(symbol)
        else:
            if s.isEmpty():
                balanced = False
            else:
                top = s.pop()
                if not matches(top,symbol):
                       balanced = False
        index = index + 1
    if balanced and s.isEmpty():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def matches(open,close):
    opens = "([{"
    closers = ")]}"
    return opens.index(open) == closers.index(close)


print(parChecker('{{([][])}()}'))
print(parChecker('[{()]'))
```

In this code each opening symbol is simply pushed on the stack to wait for the matching closing symbol to appear later in the sequence. When a closing symbol does appear, we must check to be sure that it correctly matches the type of the opening symbol on top of the stack. If the two symbols do not match, the string is not balanced. If the entire string is processed and nothing is left on the stack, the string is correctly balanced.

Comment: thanks .would ideally like to add something into my own script though as opposed to redesigning the whole thing